# Gitlab: Already have added SSH key, still permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitlab

Beginner programmer here. I outsourced code, which are on Gitlab.com. Before, if modified any code, just needed to "commit" and send thru "pipline". So SSH keys are all set and working properly.

I had to start / stop my server on AWS EC2 one day, and now get error message below on Gitlab when wanting to commit edited code and sending thru pipline:

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 11.9.0-rc2 (227934c0)
[0;m[0K  on docker-auto-scale 0277ea0f
[0;m[0KUsing Docker executor with image ruby:2.3 ...
[0;m[0KPulling docker image ruby:2.3 ...
[0;m[0KUsing docker image sha256:c505d9xxxxxxxfc90f333a5dedxxxxxxx727e6646118dd07480 for ruby:2.3 ...
[0;msection_start:1553318408:prepare_script
[0KRunning on runner-0277ea0f-project-5706649-concurrent-0 via runner-0277ea0f-srm-1553318325-a5c152d5...
section_end:1553318414:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1553318414:get_sources
[0KInitialized empty Git repository in /builds/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx_1.0/.git/
[32;1mFetching changes...[0;m
[32;1mCreated fresh repository.[0;m
From https://gitlab.com/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxx_1.0
 * [new branch]      develop    -> origin/develop
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
[32;1mChecking out 4fdf81b0 as master...[0;m

[32;1mSkipping Git submodules setup[0;m
section_end:1553318415:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1553318415:restore_cache
[0Ksection_end:1553318416:restore_cache
[0Ksection_start:1553318416:download_artifacts
[0Ksection_end:1553318418:download_artifacts
[0Ksection_start:1553318418:build_script
[0K[32;1m$ mkdir ~/.ssh[0;m
[32;1m$ echo $TARGET_SERVER_SECRET_KEY_BASE64 | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa[0;m
[32;1m$ chmod 700 ~/.ssh && chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*[0;m
[32;1m$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)[0;m
Agent pid 16
[32;1m$ ssh-add[0;m
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (/root/.ssh/id_rsa)
[32;1m$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa bot.xxxxxxx.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts[0;m
# bot.xxxxxxx.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6
[32;1m$ ssh-keyscan -t rsa gitlab.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts[0;m
# gitlab.com:22 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
[32;1m$ gem install mina[0;m
Successfully installed open4-1.3.4
Successfully installed mina-1.2.3
2 gems installed
[32;1m$ mina deploy:force_unlock[0;m
       [31mWarning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xx.xx.202' to the list of known hosts.
[0m
[32m----->[0m Unlocking
       [31mConnection to bot.xxxxxxx.com closed.
[0m
       [96mElapsed time: 1.09 seconds[0m
[32;1m$ mina deploy[0;m
[32m----->[0m Creating a temporary build path
[32m----->[0m Fetching new git commits
       Permission denied (publickey).

       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

       Please make sure you have the correct access rights
       and the repository exists.
 [33m![0m     [31mERROR: Deploy failed.
[0m
[32m----->[0m Cleaning up build
       Unlinking current
       OK
       [31mConnection to bot.xxxxxxx.com closed.
[0m
 [33m![0m     [31mRun Error[0m
section_end:1553318424:build_script
[0Ksection_start:1553318424:after_script
[0Ksection_end:1553318425:after_script
[0Ksection_start:1553318425:upload_artifacts_on_failure
[0Ksection_end:1553318427:upload_artifacts_on_failure
[0K[31;1mERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
[0;m
```

I tried ssh -vvvvT git@gitlab.com and get the error result below:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [35.231.145.151] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.com:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:HbW3g8zUjNSksFbqTiUWPWg2Bq1x8xdGUrliXFzSnUw
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from gitlab.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 35.231.145.151
debug1: Host 'gitlab.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

but the key is already set from before in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys and I didn't do any modifications to ssh (on Gitlab or server).

When rebooting, the EC2's IPv4 Public IP was changed. Is this the reason why the problem with ssh? If so, how to resolve this problem? If problem is not with IP change, then how to resolve the ssh / gitlab not being able to commit the update?

Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Asked and answered *ad nauseam* everywhere: *`Permission denied (publickey)`*. Perhaps you can state how your problem is different than the countless others.

Comment: Of course I've searched on SO already, the others are either haven't setup SSH or isn't associated with the account, but mine is already setup and pass the setup stage. As mentioned, the key is already set from before in /home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys

Answer (score 1):

For those on Gitlab and has already generated ssh public/private key before and somehow receive the error msg similar to above, try:

cd into your project .ssh directory:

```
    eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/your_keyfile_name
```